# How to use Thymeleaf to process YAML files?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, template-engine

I'm trying to process YAML files using Thymeleaf. A sample file is given below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: [[${app['name']}]]
  labels:
    app: [[${app['name']}]]
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

The value `app.name` comes from another YAML file that I parse at runtime.

What I've tried so far:

1. Creating a `MessageSource` with `Properties`

   ```
   TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
   templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
   StandardMessageResolver messageResolver = new StandardMessageResolver();
   messageResolver.setDefaultMessages(props); // contains app.name
   templateEngine.setMessageResolver(messageResolver);
   ```
2. Setting a variable in the context

   ```
   map.put("app.name", "test");
   context.setVariables(map); // contains app.name
   ```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "app['name']
...
Caused by: ognl.OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "name")
```

Using Thymeleaf 3.0.3.RELEASE. I'm using Spring and not using Spring, in the sense that the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` brings in so much baggage mostly needed for HTML, I decided to just instantiate the template resolver and engine myself. It seems like people rarely process TEXT using Thymeleaf; all the examples I came across are HTML.

I'd also like to know how to include a fragment of YAML in my templates.

**Edit**:
Thanks to @Metroids, I got it working. Here's the [link](https://github.com/asarkar/spring/tree/master/template-resolver) to my sample app in case someone else has a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some confusion about how to access properties here... if you want to use the expression `${app['name']}` in your template, your context should look like this:

```
Map<String, Object> app = new HashMap<>();
app.put("name", "test");

Context context = new Context();
context.setVariable("app", app);
engine.process("template", context);
```

Using `map.put("app.name", "test");` is not a good idea because a syntax of `something.something` has a meaning in expression language (calling a getter/setter on an object).

Edit: Including a text template would look something like this:

**a.txt**

```
blah blah blah 
[# th:insert="b"/] 
blah blah blah
```

**b.txt**

```
Text in b.txt
that should be included
```

Edit 2: If you want to use messages, rather than a context this should work:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: [[#{app.name}]]
  labels:
    app: [[#{app.name}]]
```

Comment: That's what I eventually did. I was under the impression that the `MessageResolver` is able to resolve `app.name` as that's a common format for message keys, but it didn't.
Please update your response with the fragment include as well, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Ah, you're the same person on the thymeleaf forums... got it, haha.

Comment: I found that `[# th:text="#{app.name}"/]` works for messages too. Your syntax is more concise though. Thanks for the help. For benefit of those to come, I've edited my question to include a link to the sample app I am working on.